# Hide checkout shipping fields section for specific shipping method in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method

Someone asked the following question that I have answered. Then he delete it. So I publish the question and my answer back as this can be useful for the community:

In WooCommerce, I am trying to update a checkbox form dynamically without reloading the checkout page.
I have 2 shipping methods: "Delivery" and "Collect". I am trying to only disable the shipping address section *(with the "ship to another address if chosen method is collect" checkbox option)* and all shipping fields.

First I tried this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shipping_rate', 'carrier_custom_fields', 30, 2 );
function carrier_custom_fields( $method, $index ) {
    if( ! is_checkout()) return; // Only on checkout page

    $customer_carrier_method = 'local_pickup:1';


    if( $method->id != $customer_carrier_method ) return; // Only display for "local_pickup"

    $chosen_method_id = WC()->session->chosen_shipping_methods[ $index ];

    // echo $chosen_method_id;

    // If the chosen shipping method is 'legacy_local_pickup' we display
    if($chosen_method_id == $customer_carrier_method ):

        add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address', '__return_false');

    else :
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address', '__return_true');


    endif;

}
```

Then I tried this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shipping_method_chosen', 'check_if_local_pickup', 10, 1 );
function check_if_local_pickup( $chosen_method ) {
    $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0]; 
    if ($chosen_shipping == 'local_pickup:1') { 
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_ship_to_different_address_checked', '__return_false' );
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address', '__return_false');
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address', '__return_true');
        return true;

    }
}
```

Both of them doesn't work.

How to hide checkout shipping fields section for specific chosen shipping method in WooCommerce?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP is not the way as this an event on a "client side" *(not on "server side")*, so it requires to use jQuery. So to hide shipping fields section for a specific shipping method, you will use the following:

```
// Auto Show hide checkout shipping fields section based on chosen shipping methods
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_field_script' );
function custom_checkout_field_script() {
    // Only on checkout page
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ):

    // HERE below define your local pickup shipping method
    $local_pickup = 'local_pickup:1';

    // Jquery code start
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            var a = 'checked',      
                b = 'input#ship-to-different-address-checkbox', 
                c = 'input[name^="shipping_method"]',   
                d = '<?php echo $local_pickup; ?>',     
                e = c + ':' + a
                f = 'div.woocommerce-shipping-fields,' + b;

            // 1. On load: when the chosen shipping method is our defined shipping method
            if( $(e).val() === d ) {
                // Hide shipping fields section
                $(f).hide(); 
            }

            // 2. On shipping method "change" (Live event)
            $( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'change', c, function() {
                // When the chosen shipping method is our defined shipping method
                if( $(e).val() === d ) {
                    // if the checkbox is checked, uncheck it first
                    if ( $(b).prop(a) ) {
                        $(b).click();
                    }

                    // Hide shipping fields section
                    $(f).hide();
                } else if ( $(e).val() !== d ) {
                    // show closed shipping fields section with (unchecked checkbox)
                    $(f).show();                    
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related: [How to make ship to different address checked when using Free Shipping and Flat Rate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61650202/how-to-make-ship-to-different-address-checked-when-using-free-shipping-and-flat/61665664#61665664)